# How to cast data from array in Laravel / Eloquent in model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Can someone please tell me how can I achieve something in a Laravel Model?

One of the columns contains `json_encoded` data:

```
["1", "7", "13", "18"]
```

I have a model for this specific table and when I'm trying to get the data from different tables based on those `ids`, it won't work as variable is always `null`:

```
use App\Models\VehiculeType;
...

class Freight extends Model
{
    ...
    public function selected_vt() {
        return VehiculeType::whereIn('id', json_decode($this->vehicules))
            ->get();
    }
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
$freights = Freight::with('selected_vt')
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->get();
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, null given

I am sure I'm making some fundamental error trying to do this in the completely wrong way.

Comment: try `dump($this->vehicules)`. I'm guessing it's not a valid JSON string and is therefore returning `null`. Or maybe you have cast it. I'd recommend casting it to an array: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting -- that way all you would need is `VehiculeType::whereIn('id', $this->vehicules)`

Comment: You can't use [`with`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) as you expect... `with` works with `relations` not with literal queries or data...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't use `with` with collection, and `selected_vt` must return relation instance rather than a collection.

Try eloquent-json-relations package, it can helps you with your situation:
https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-json-relations

Here is an example depending your situation

After installing package

in Freight Modle

```
class Freight extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    protected $casts = [
       'vehicules' => 'json'
    ];

    public function vehicules()
    {
        return $this->belongsToJson(VehiculeType::class, 'vehicules');
    }
}
```

If you want the reversed relation

in VehiculeType Model

```
class VehiculeType extends Model
{
    use \Staudenmeir\EloquentJsonRelations\HasJsonRelationships;

    public function freights()
    {
       return $this->hasManyJson(Freight::class, 'vehicules');
    }
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
$freights = Freight::with('vehicules')
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->get();
```